# Contour data rotation in python in dicom image

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, dicom

I have a huge data text file. I plot these data on a CT image which results can be seen on the below image. But how could I rotate my dose data axis to be same with my CT image ?

[image]

**My code so far:**

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import dicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import islice
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm
data = dicom.read_file("NEW.dcm")
plt.set_cmap("gray")

pixel_array = data.pixel_array

plt.pcolormesh(pixel_array)
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
CS=plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,cmap=plt.cm.jet)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.loadtxt('New.txt')
i = a[:,1]
j = a[:,2]
energies = a[:,3]
xi = np.linspace(i.min(), i.max())
yi = np.linspace(j.min(), j.max())
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((i, j), energies, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
fig = plt.figure()
CS=plt.contour(xi, yi, zi,colors='k',  norm=plt.Normalize(vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max()))
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

**Data extract**

```
30  1   2   0.00951305
30  1   3   0.0110269
30  1   4   0.0141366
30  1   5   0.00468656
30  1   6   0.0144487
30  1   7   0.0253241
30  1   8   0.0239877
30  1   9   0.0175475
30  1   10  0.0134009
…
```

(Full code and data available [here](https://pastebin.com/0SrGVHdf))

Thanks you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Imported code and data from external resource. Put image in the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transpose `z` grid, you will have the contours rotated. In last two lines change `z` to `z.T`:

```
CS=plt.contour(xi, yi, zi.T,colors='k', norm=plt.Normalize(vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max()))
CS = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi.T,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

Remember that in images `X` axis is horizontal and `Y` is vertical, but for matrices 1st dimension (`X`) is vertical and 2nd (`Y`) is horizontal.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Would you like to consider the answer to resolve as "accepted"?